# Minishift: Could not resolve: *.192.168.64.2.nip.io

Tags: openshift-origin, minishift

I have installed **minishift** on OSX with brew:

```
brew cask install minishift-beta
...

$ minishift version
Minishift version: 1.0.0
```

I have sucessfuly started minishift, and created *node-ex* example application and exported it:

```
$ oc get route
NAME        HOST/PORT                                 PATH      SERVICES    PORT       TERMINATION   WILDCARD
nodejs-ex   nodejs-ex-myproject.192.168.64.2.nip.io             nodejs-ex   8080-tcp                 None
```

However I can not reach *.192.168.64.2.nip.io*:

```
$ curl nodejs-ex-myproject.192.168.64.2.nip.io
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nodejs-ex-myproject.192.168.64.2.nip.io


$ dig +short nodejs-ex-myproject.192.168.64.2.nip.io
$
```

All is working with minishift web console and *oc* command, but I can not reach the application domain.

Comment: Hi! could you share us, the output of `minishift ip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something on your machine or network blocking DNS queries to `nip.io`?

Comment: I need a resolver to `*.192.168.64.2.nip.io`   I understand that minishift must configure when start.

If I create a line into `/etc/hosts` like:

    `192.168.64.2  nodejs-ex-myproject.192.168.64.2.nip.io`

all is working ok.   But `/etc/hosts` do not enable to configure a wilcard domain.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you @enj. The explanation at http://nip.io is clear about how it works.

I have seen that queries to `8.8.8.8` and to my ISP DNS are resolved to my private IP.   But it is my router (my primary DNS) which do respond `nip.io`

My router run DD-WRT and has enabled

```
Rebind protection   Discard upstream RFC1918 responses
```

then I add `nip.io` at

```
Domain whitelist    nip.io
```

and now I resolve queries:

```
≻ dig +short test.10.0.0.1.nip.io
10.0.0.1
```

Comment: Rebind protection in DD-WRT was also preventing me from resolving nip.io. You can add this under "Additional DNSMasq Options": `rebind-domain-ok=/.nip.io/`

Answer (score 0):

When playing with Minishift at home, where I am connected to the internet via **Deutsche Telekom**'s VDSL and Speedport-Router, I cannot resolve these **`xip.io`** or **`nip.io`** addresses.

My workaround is to put **`8.8.8.8`** into **`/etc/resolv.conf`**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows 10.  My workaround was to add an entry in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.  Here is an example

`192.160.90.101 nodejs-ex-nodejs-echo.192.160.90.101.nip.io     # needed for minishift to work`