# Minishift hyper-v works but cannot resolve .nip.io addresses

Tags: hyper-v, minishift

I have downloaded and followed the install instructions for minishift v1.6.0+7a71565. 
I am running windows10 with hyper-v. I have created a virtual switch that is connected to my wireless card.

I can create projects/pods etc fine and the creation downloads images and git source directories and starts the pods. In the logs I can see that wildfly is running.

I now want to display these web applications in a browser on the host machine.
I add a route and get an route like this
    http://test-tpcc.192.168.171.212.nip.io

When I paste this route into the browser it gives me a DNS error. I can reach nip.io ok so I dont know what to do from here. I have tried using the dockerNAT but then minishift fails to start the cluster. I have also just used 192.168.171.212 but then i get an openshift web page that tells me this application is not running/accepting connections. I guess the pod name mapping is important.

Any clues gratefully received

graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looked at this issue [Minishift: Could not resolve: *.192.168.64.2.nip.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834159/minishift-could-not-resolve-192-168-64-2-nip-io)

The solution being to add 8.8.8.8 to /etc/resolv.conf.

On windows to do the same thing I set the DNS server for the network to be 8.8.8.8 in my tcp/ip properties. Once I did this my pods with external routes in minishift were visible in my host/windows browsers.

[image: Properties Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

One fix to this is to configure a wildcard DNS entry.
I use posadis for this: http://posadis.sourceforge.net/download

Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Posadis 0.60.6
run mfedit.exe
CLick New
In zone root enter 192.168.171.212.nip.io. with dot at the end
in IP number for this dns server enter 127.0.0.1
Click OK

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axgx4.png)

Click Insert --> IP4, domain * ip 192.168.171.212
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b74Sx.png)

click save. save under C:\Program Files (x86)\Posadis 0.60.6\Config as 192.168.171.212.nip.io.prm

No run posadis.exe

you can use dnsquery.exe to verify
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se5tE.png)

No add 127.0.0.1 to your dns resolve and test with ping

Answer (score 0):

In my case, DNS was resolving, but after resolution, our corporate proxy was blocking HTTP traffic to anything ending in nip.io. The workaround was to set a local proxy bypass for *.nip.io.